# vectorization of "cumulated" expected values from regression

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

I have data

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(t=1:1000,x1=runif(1000,1,10),x2=round(runif(1000,0,1)))
dat$y <- 8*dat$x1 - 5*dat$x2 + rnorm(1000)

> head(dat)
  t       x1 x2        y
1 1 9.233254  1 71.19109
2 2 9.433679  0 75.99355
3 3 3.575256  1 24.57278
4 4 8.474029  1 63.16920
5 5 6.775710  0 53.20974
6 6 5.671864  0 44.77743
```

where `t` gives points in time. I would like to obtain the expected value of `y` at each point in time based on a regression of `y` on `x1` and `x2` using the preceding points in time.

I could do this in a for-loop but I wonder whether there is a solution with `data.table`. In a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531250/vectorization-of-cumulative-regression), Michael Chirico gave an excellent hint on how to do the regression and get the coefficients,

```
dat[dat, on=.(t<t), allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch=0L][ , as.list(coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))), keyby = t]
```

but using them to get the expected values would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you want something like this :

```
dat[dat, on=.(t<t), allow.cartesian = TRUE, nomatch=0L][ , .( exp=predict(lm(y ~ x1 + x2),list(x1=i.x1[1],x2=i.x2[1]))), keyby = t]

       t        exp
  1:    2  71.191094
  2:    3 -64.382779
  3:    4  64.935556
  4:    5  54.437024
  5:    6  44.693841
 ---                
995:  996  17.828209
996:  997  47.443171
997:  998  12.177957
998:  999  43.640271
999: 1000   3.516452
```

Anyway, that method might be terribly inefficient in terms of memory usage (e.g. this small example already creates a throw-away data.table of 499500 rows !).

I would use a simple for-loop without the need of data.table (it takes more or less the same time) :

```
expected <- rep.int(NA,nrow(dat))
for(n in 2:nrow(dat)){
  LM <- lm(y~x1+x2,data=dat[1:(n-1),])
  expVal <- predict(LM,dat[n,])
  expected[n] <- expVal
}
dat$exp <- expected

> dat
        t       x1 x2         y        exp
1       1 9.233254  1 71.191094         NA
2       2 9.433679  0 75.993552  71.191094
3       3 3.575256  1 24.572780 -64.382779
4       4 8.474029  1 63.169202  64.935556
5       5 6.775710  0 53.209744  54.437024
6       6 5.671864  0 44.777425  44.693841
7       7 7.629295  1 56.199610  57.353776
```